# explain: why does someone need to load img 1x1 pixel out of screen?

Tags: image, noscript

What may be the purpose of loading an image of size 1x1 pixel inside `noscript` block?

```
<noscript>
    <img src="https://vk.com/rtrg?p=VK-RTRG-218928-gWfNz" style="position:fixed; left:-999px;" alt=""/>
</noscript>
```

Please explain this snippet that I've found when investigating tinkoff.ru page source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Retargeting Pixel - a small, unobtrusive piece of code on somebody's website. The code, or pixel, is unnoticeable to site visitors and won’t affect site’s performance. It is a form of online advertising that allows collecting statistics about the visitors.

Quote from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31034812/1429387)

> The server hosting the 1x1 px image logs the request. This allows collecting statistics about who loads (and renders) the page with the image. Browsers in general allow cross origin in img tags.

The `<noscript>` tag content is shown for users that have disabled scripts in their browser or have a browser that doesn't support script.